# html contents of angular 6 universal app not rendered on view page source

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular6, angular-universal

I have installed my angular 6 universal app on an apache server. Server side rendering (SSR) works fine but when I view page source on the home page, it does not show the html elements inside router-outlet. On other pages it works fine.

More info on my app:

- it is served through an express server on http://localhost:9000
- I used .htaccess to forward to port 9000 i.e. mydomain.com to mydomain.com:9000
- going to mydomain.com:9000 directly and viewing page source shows the html elements inside router-outlet
- mydomain.com/route1, mydomain.com/route2 and viewing page source shows the elements inside router-outlet as well
- mydomain.com and viewing page source does not show the html elements inside router-outlet

below is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to 9000 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^9000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:9000/$1 [P,L]
```

I've been struggling with this for the past days and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears that I missed adding a wildcard route and when I added it fixed the issue.